# Do we have any software to check plagiarism in SOPs and LORs?

Tags: recommendation-letter, plagiarism, statement-of-purpose

Softwares like Turnitin and IThenticate serve the purpose for the plagiarism check of the documents, but they have their own databases to check from and compare with the provided document.

According to the https://uwaterloo.ca/academic-integrity/integrity-instructors-and-tas/turnitin-and-ithenticate,

> Turnitin can be used as both a plagiarism tool and an educational tool. Turnitin generates ‘similarity reports’ on student submissions which can provide instructors with information about plagiarized sources. The reports can also be used as part of a formative or low-stakes assessment to help students understand the proper use of quotation marks, how to cite sources properly, and how to paraphrase.

> iThenticate is plagiarism detection software that is designed to be used by researchers to ensure the originality of written work before publication. For example, graduate students and researchers can check their articles and book chapters to be submitted for publication, grant proposals, theses and dissertations.

**These softwares are usually not available to the working professionals outside academia.**

Are there any good softwares which can be used to check plagiarism in LORs and SOPs?

Comment: Authors should never need to use software to check for plagiarism.

Comment: @ Anonymous Physicist, why so?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire Because if you wrote a paper, you wrote it yourself, and then it will not contain parts which have been plagiarized from somewhere else. You shouldn't take someone else's paper - regardless how well it is written - and start to change it until it no longer looks like plagiarized.  Same solds for SOPs and so forth.

Comment: Would Turnitin really refuse to accept a customer from outside academia?

Comment: @user151413 I can remember Paul McCartney giving an interview, in which he mentioned that he'd accidentally plagiarized the same song on several occasions, but had always been fortunate enough to have someone in the room with him who was able to warn him of the similarity, before he could release his "composition" and expose himself to litigation.  I guess that makes John Lennon (or whoever else it was) a sort of human Turnitin.  And I further guess that an analogous process could happen with a prose document.

Comment: @DanielHatton Song tunes are rather different from several page long scientific papers. No-one is talking about having one sentence or so identical to a sentence found somewhere else.  Differently speaking: Any kind of "unintentional plagiarism" as you describe is not plagiarism.  It's the kind of thing which you know when you see it.

Comment: @user151413 The academic regulations at every university where I've ever worked have explicitly said that an unintentional or accidental act of copying without proper attribution still constitutes plagiarism.

Comment: @DanielHatton Yes, but here we are not talking about *copying*, but about accidentally writing the very same sentence.  This can happen for a reasonably short sentence, but not for a longer part of the text consisting of several sentences.  So I think one can credibly distinguish if one accidentally wrote the same text, or if one actually *copied* the text, even if unintentionally.

Comment: @user151413 I don't think the two are empirically distinguishable.  I haven't got a record of everything I read in 1986.  So if I accidentally write the same text as Bloggs (1984), I don't know whether that's because I've coincidentally composed the same text independently, or whether it's because I read Bloggs (1984) at some point during 1986, forgot that I'd read it, but subconsciously remembered some of its content.

Comment: @DanielHatton I'd say this only applies if you have a photographis memory. Otherwise, if you made very detailed excerpts and then "paraphrased" them literally, this is somewhat intentional.

Comment: In my field, SOP = standard operating procedure!? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @cbeleites Statement of purpose? (i.e. research statement)

Answer (score 2):

If a statement of purpose or a letter of recommendation is so generic that it could legitimately have been written about two different applicants, it's a pretty bad one to start with. I honestly don't see the point. And to answer the question, no, to my knowledge, there is no such database.